# How Do I Find Out If An Object Is Locked? c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, locking

I have a lock in my code.
I have two threads running at the same time.
  How can I tell if a thread is locking that object?

```
private readonly object _lockObject = new Object();

// Both methods running
public void Method1()
{
    if(certainCriteria)
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
        //doWork;
        }
    }
}

// Both methods running
public void Method2()
{
    if( isLocked?(_lockObject))
    {
        //doWork;
    }
}
```

Has anyone got the isLocked? method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx) (either with a timeout of 0, or the overload which doesn't take a timeout at all) and then immediately call [`Monitor.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx) if it succeeds - but I'd say this is generally a bad design smell. In particular, the data is stale immediately you return it.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jon: Yaow is too quick, yaaw is (reads better if you can manage a Black country accent).  It was what I was going to suggest with a huge caveat "It works on the basis the we "know" how lock works".

Comment: I'm not particularly bothered by the fact that it depends on knowing how lock works - it's not like that's going to change. It's just that it feels plain wrong. I dare say there are *some* situations where it's useful, but probably fewer than the places where it's actually used!

Comment: Hi again Jon! I am implementing a BufferManager.  Basically it has a Stack of Buffers.  When a thread pop()s the stack and it is empty - I want all threads to wait on their next pop() while a thread fills up the stack.  Once filled - all other threads to keep on poping.  I am unsure as to the c# locking mechanisms though!

Comment: I'm not sure why that would require you to conditionally lock. Use Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse/PulseAll and I'd expect you to be okay. Which part of your BufferManager would you want to conditionally lock?

Comment: So this is a producer-consumer pattern?  You have some threads producing items and putting them on a list, and some threads consuming the items, and removing them? If so, this is a well-studied pattern; there's lots of literature on how to properly implement this pattern.